# Complex scenario with ASP .NET MVC 3 without using Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a model class called House:

```
public class House
{
    public House()
    {
        Residents = new List<Resident>();
    }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }     
    ...  
    public virtual IList<Resident> Residents{ get; set; }
}

public class Resident
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Age{ get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
}
```

So, in my view Create (House), I need to add Residents . So I added a button "Add Resident", that opens a JQuery UI Modal with Create(Resident) and when the user click Confirm, the Modal closes and my Resident´s grid refresh...

My problem here is where I save that list ... I did that using Session... But I´d like to do that without Session...

What I´ve done (My House Controller):

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult AddResident(Resident resident)  //Called when user confirms modal Resident
  {
      Residents.Add(resident);

      return PartialView("_Residents", Residents);
  }

  public Collection<Resident> Residents
  {
      get
      {
          if (Session["Residents"] == null)
          {
              var _lista = new Collection<Resident>();

              Session["Residents"] = _lista;
              return _lista;
          }
          return (Collection<Resident>)Session["Residents"];
      }
      set { Session["Residents"] = value; }
  }
```

So, what´s the right way to do that kind of scenario without session?

Thanks

Comment: Why do not want to serialize the data between posts?  What is your requirement that prevents you from saving this data to a data store?

Comment: I can only save residents on db when user saves the house...

Comment: Why do you try avoiding `session`? it's there for those kind of needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it stil uses the `Session` behind the scene, `TempData` is the [way to go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) when you want to persist data across actions calls.

> An action method can store data in the controller's TempDataDictionary object before it calls the controller's RedirectToAction method to invoke the next action. The TempData property value is stored in session state.

The good part is that the session will be automatically cleared after your read (in your grid refresh method). It's really what it means "temporary data".

Here's a sample of code with `TempData`:

```
public ActionResult AddResident(Resident resident)
{
    IList<Resident> residents = PeristResident(resident);
    return PartialView("_Residents", residents);
}

private IList<Resident> PeristResident(Resident resident)
{
    IList<Resident> residents = Residents; // this operation can empty TempData by reading it
    residents.Add(resident);
    Residents = residents; // so we persists collection after read
    return residents;
}

private IList<Resident> Residents
{
    get
    {
        object results;
        if (TempData.TryGetValue("Residents", out results) == false)
        {
            var list = new List<Resident>();
            return list;
        }
        return (IList<Resident>)results;

    }
    set { TempData["Residents"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: And if the user refresh the page, "All is lost"... Risky I would say.

Comment: Indeed but that seems logic to me that the user loses his data if he refresh the page without saving. It's more bad to keep a list in memory if you don't need it anymore imho.

Comment: You can clear the collection from the session when you're done.

Comment: True. But I was thinking at a case such as the user decides to navigate away from your page (juste leaving the page, not the website). Your session will not be cleared, isn't it? The problem is the definition of done. Both solutions have pros and cons.

Comment: I tried to replace the Session with TempData, but my Resident list doesnt keep the values... TempData is always clearing my values...

Comment: That's because you retrieve the value from `TempData` each time you add a item and it's cleared. Try to change your code like [this](http://codepaste.net/8avo1e).

Answer (score 2):

You're not too far off the mark with using session. As MVC doesn't have the rather bloated (and often ugly) viewstate, you need to store your residents collection somewhere. You basically have 3 options:

**1. Use an editable list approach.**

This is where you post back the whole list each time to ensure your model maintains its state. (look at this example: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

**Problems:** You have to deal with the list wanting to validate every time you post it back which can be a problem if you have validation rules on your House form.

**2. Create a client side javascript solution.**

This will add new items to your list and in doing so, will store the values for those items in hidden inputs ensuring the full model is submitted in the end. This can be tricky as you then need to manage the index of each item in markup that javascript creates. For example changing this:

```
name="House.Residents[0].Name" id="House.Residents_0__Name"
```

To the index you need when you add an item. This is the approach i generally take, but it can be complicated. The code to take a returned empty editor template from MVC and reset its index is as follows:

```
function (response, index, oldindex) {
            // Reset editor template index reference
            response.attr("id", response.attr("id").replace("[" + oldindex + "]", "[" + index + "]"));
            var inputList = response.find("input, select");
            inputList.each(function (num) {
                var thisEl = $(this);
                // Allow for dbl input with checkbox
                if (thisEl.attr("id"))
                    thisEl.attr("id", thisEl.attr("id").replace("_" + oldindex + "__", "_" + index + "__"));
                thisEl.attr("name", thisEl.attr("name").replace("[" + oldindex + "]", "[" + index + "]"));
            });
            var spanList = response.find("span");
            spanList.each(function (num) {
                var thisEl = $(this);
                if (thisEl.attr("data-valmsg-for")) {
                    thisEl.attr("data-valmsg-for", thisEl.attr("data-valmsg-for").replace("[" + oldindex + "]", "[" + index + "]"));
                }
            });
            var labelList = response.find("label");
            labelList.each(function (num) {
                var thisEl = $(this);
                if (thisEl.attr("for")) {
                    thisEl.attr("for", thisEl.attr("for").replace("_" + oldindex + "__", "_" + index + "__"));
                }
            });
            return response;
        }
```

**3. Use session (or tempdata).**

to temporarily store your list is by far the easiest, but probably the least graceful.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Cookies
2. Hidden fields.

But I think session is a good approach for this scenario.